# Microsoft Flow "ignores" Mails with certificate

Tags: email, email-attachments, smime, power-automate

at the moment we're using Microsoft Flow for specific workflows.
The Flow does detach the attachment of an E-Mail. This step is not working when an E-Mail is send with a certificate. I've attached an example for what I mean:
[image: Certificate Mail Screenshot (Red symbol)]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What I have observed: When an email is S/MIME signed, Flow detects only one attachment: the S/MIME signature. It does not detect other attachments.
Is that what you mean? Flow does detect the mail itself.
I assume that Flow only parses the outer MIME structure (in this case multipart/signed) and not the inner one (multipart/mixed).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Flow seems not to support content inspection of S/MIME-signed emails including finding their attachments. I have tested this for clear signed emails as well as enveloped signed emails.

You could possibly write a MIME or S/MIME parser in Flow, but I think it will be ugly.

Instead, you can at least create a condition to **detect** S/MIME signed emails and do some error handling like pushing a warning notification that the flow failed due to the incompatibility. If you have a foreach-loop for the attachments, then inside the loop, the following condition detects S/MIME signed mails (use advanced mode to enter):

`@or(equals(items('Apply_to_each')?['ContentType'], 'multipart/signed'),equals(items('Apply_to_each')?['ContentType'], 'application/pkcs7-mime'))`

`multipart/signed` is for clear signed S/MIME signatures, `application/pkcs7-mime` is for enveloped S/MIME signatures.